# set the value of jprogressbar to zero after reached 100%

Tags: java, netbeans, jprogressbar

how to set the value of jprogressbar to zero after reached the 100%?

i used the following code but didn't do exactly what i want:

```
private void jButton6ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    Thread runner = new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            counter = pb_MINIMUM;
            while(counter <= pb_MAXIMUM){
                Runnable runme = new Runnable(){
                    public void run(){
                        jProgressBar1.setValue(counter);
                    }
                };
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(runme);
                counter++;
                try{
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                }catch(Exception e){
                }
            }
        }
    };
    runner.start();
    if(jProgressBar1.getMaximum()==pb_MAXIMUM){
        jProgressBar1.setValue(0);
    }
}
```

thanks for any help i could get here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your call of `setValue(0)` occurs directly after you started the thread (which does all the work and increases value of progress bar). At this time no work was done yet and the method does not wait for your thread to complete. Instead you may just include the code right after your while loop (same as you do inside but with value of zero).